# Logo in nav bar is pushing li next to it down

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with building a nav bar for my website.  I have a logo aligned to the right but it is forcing the rest of li to align to the bottom of the logo.  How can I make the list items align horizontally center.

```
<nav class="main_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home"><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="images/logo.svg"></a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#about" class="li_nav">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#trips" class="li_nav">Trips</a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#projects" class="li_nav">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#donations" class="li_nav">Donations</a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#sponsors" class="li_nav">Sponsors</a></li>
                <li class="list_item"><a href="#contact" class="li_nav">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.main_nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.li_nav {
  color: #939598;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  display: inline;
}

.logo {
  min-width: 115px;
  max-width: 125px;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-top: .25em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.list_item {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: put ur logo outside the nav in seprate div

Comment: @MandarSant when I do that it pushes the nav bar under the logo, how would I align them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main_nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
}
li .li_nav{
  color: #939598;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  display:block;
  line-height:50px
  
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><a href="#home"><img alt="logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#about" class="li_nav">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#trips" class="li_nav">Trips</a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#projects" class="li_nav">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#donations" class="li_nav">Donations</a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#sponsors" class="li_nav">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li class="list_item"><a href="#contact" class="li_nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For align horizontally center, depends on your image size and change the line-height accordingly

Answer (score 1):

is this outpur r u expecting

check the output in  [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xilubuv/edit?html,css)

modify ur css as follows

```
  li{
list-style:none;
float:right;
margin-right:100px;
}

.list_item{
position:relative;
top:-35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add float:right property to your class "logo"

```
.logo{
float:right;
}
```

also add the class "list_item" to logo li container

Comment: won't that just push the logo to the right side and keep the nav bar below it?

Comment: You were right,  i forgot to mention that i add the list_item class to the li that contaist the logo